# Omitting the popup title

Tags: popup

I assume this question was already answered but I can't find it.
Is a popup title something recommeded, even if the user already knows why he got the popup? For example, imagine that I want to see the details from a invoice in a list. Is it recommended to show something like "Invoice Details"? Or is it better omitting it and get more room for the invoice details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary to have a popup title or any relevant information that will confirm to the user that what they have clicked is what they have in the popup. User might be performing multiple tasks at once, maybe they will open up the popup then answer a call, when they return to the screen, expecting them to remember what specific invoice they have clicked on is too much.